# modelling: npm install error

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to install modelling node module using npm. Here is the link https://www.npmjs.org/package/modelling

It keeps throwing me an error.  No compatible version found: waterline@'balderdashy/waterline'

I have installed all the dependencies of modelling separately i.e. waterline, lodash, express, extend.
Still it throws me the same error. Anyone knows a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I see, in package.json :

> "waterline": "balderdashy/waterline"

Is this a correct semantic version? Try replace it with "*" (any versions) and see.

Hope it's help!

Comment: But I actually want to download a module openid-connect which depends on modelling. When I manually download openid-connect and use npm install in it.The download of modelling refers to balderdashy/waterline.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe modelling is a peer dependency to openid-connect, if so It have to be bundled in node_modules folder of openid-connect. Give it a try and tell us.

Comment: https://github.com/agmoyano/OpenIDConnect After downloading this, you have to do npm install in the directory so that it downloads all the dependencies from package.json file. So it will try to download modelling which will try to download waterline giving the same error.